# Flex: How do I check what the parent of a DisplayObject is?

Tags: apache-flex, parent

How can I check what the parent of a displayObject is? What is the parent of myObject for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's myObject.parent. Sorry about that.

-Laxmidi

Comment: I was going to say that, but you beat me to it :)